# caffe: libglog.so.0 missing (error while loading shared libraries)

Tags: caffe

I've installed caffe on a server a while ago, and back then it worked properly.

Now I'm following the LeNet MNIST tutorial again (http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/mnist.html), and running

```
./examples/mnist/create_mnist.sh
```

returns

```
build/examples/mnist/convert_mnist_data.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libglog.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've noticed that liibglog.so.0 is not in /lib which might be the reason for it, but I'm not allowed to copy that file into /lib directory, since I'm not a root user.

Is there workaround for this?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to achieve by running `ldconfig`?

Comment: I have a problem running caffe which I installed and checked to work correctly, but not working now. I did some googling, and some people say ldconfig may help..

Comment: If you post more details about your _actual_ problem, you may be able to get help with that. There isn't really a workaround to lack of root, but there are many workarounds to running applications that default to requiring root but don't need it.

Comment: thanx I've edited the question as advised.

Comment: Do you have a copy of ` liibglog.so.0 ` somewhere else on your filesystem?

Comment: yes, it's in ~/local/lib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to work around the lack of shared libraries in system directories is to use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with the directory where the shared library lives.

Before running the the command that requires a library, run the following in the following the same shell.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/local/lib
```

You can also stick this in your `.bashrc` for convenience.

An alternate solution is to use the following command line flag while compiling, but that requires mucking with other people's build scripts.

```
 -Wl,-rpath,$(DEFAULT_LIB_INSTALL_PATH)
```